# Como debugar python no Visual Studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, debug, visual-studio-code

Tenho a seguinte estrutura e pastas e arquivos:

```
DebugTeste
         |--br
             |--com
                  |--empresa
                           |--implementacao
                           |              |--__init__.py 
                           |              |--Ola.py
                           |
                           |--testes
                                   |--testeOlaMundo
```

`__init__.py` código:

```
# __init__.py
from .Ola import OlaMundo
```

`Ola.py` código:

```
class OlaMundo():
    def OlaMundoMensagem():
        return "Olá Mundo"
```

`testeOlaMundo.py` código:

```
from br.com.empresa.implementacao.Ola import OlaMundo

OlaTexto = OlaMundo.OlaMundoMensagem()

print(OlaTexto)
```

Quando vou *debugar* o `testeOlaMundo` pelo Visual Studio Code, ocorre o seguinte erro,

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No nodule named br'
```

Comment: Essa importação só funcionará se você instalar o módulo. Você pode fazer algo como `from ..implementacao.Ola import OlaMundo`, indicando a importação relativa.

Comment: Baixe esta [extensão](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), siga este [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial), para mais informações do python no visual studio olhe [esta página](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python), sugiro que leia cuidadosamente cada passo tanto da página da extensão quanto do tutorial para que não ocorra nenhum erro.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, fiz o recomendado, porem obtive "attempted relative import with no known parent package". Para executar corretamente criei uma arquivo main.py no mesmo nivel da pasta br, nele chamo o arquivo testeOlaMundo.py

Comment: Por curiosidade, por que está criando módulos dentro de tantos pacotes assim? Isso parece ser o padrão de Java ou Go, mas no Python não há motivos para fazer assim.

Comment: Anderson, estou fazendo alguns testes, se eu for trabalhar com um projeto grande terei que criar pacotes para organizar as coisas